# A single string in single quotes with PyYAML

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

When I edit a YAML file in Python with PyYAML, all of my string values are saved back to the original file without quotes.

```
one: valueOne
two: valueTwo
three: valueThree
```

I wanted one of those strings to be surrounded with single quotes:

```
one: valueOne
two: valueTwo
three: 'valueThree'
```

Changing the `default_style` parameter in `yaml_dump` affects whole file, which is not desired. I thought about adding single quotes to the beginning and end of a string that I want to be surrounded with:

```
valueThreeVariable = "'" + valueThreeVariable + "'"
```

However, this ends up with a dumped YAML looking like this:

```
one: valueOne
two: valueTwo
three: '''valueThree'''
```

I have tried escaping the single quote in various ways, using unicode or raw strings, all to no avail.
How can I make only one of my YAML values to be a string surrounded with single quotes?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Here's something to try. Don't know whether it will work -- I've never used PyYaml. Try this: valueThreeVariable = " '{0}' ".format(valueThreeVariable). Note the spaces inside the double quotes around the single quotes.

Comment: @TomBarron unfortunately this formats the single string in `' ''StringHere'' '` way

Comment: @busfault's question wasn't rhetorical. We can't really tell you the best solution if you don't tell us what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: A config I am trying to build has exact requirements, which I need to fulfill. I don't have too much to say here :(

Comment: @3yakuya: That's interesting. http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation has examples that seem to indicate the possibility of embedded single quotes. Also, there's a "single-quoted" style defined (see the Scalars section), which implies support for what you're trying to do. Perhaps investigate that? It seems odd that you would be able to load a single quoted value but not emit one. Perhaps try loading a single quoted value and see how it winds up represented in your running program. Sorry I'm not able to be more helpful.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions! I just found it surprising that just appending `'` to the start and end of a string does not work, and apparently there is no easy solution for that! But this is probably not a typical use-case.

Comment: @TomMyddeltyn here is a good reason why I need to do it:  I need to generate yaml configs for netplan.io on ubuntu to setup wifi. The config of netplan requires wifi ssid in double quotes and the password in double quotes as well, but nothing else.

https://netplan.io/examples

Comment: @3yakuya have you found any simple solution? I am facing same issue but the difference is instead of PyYaml I'm using YAML module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can graft such functionality onto PyYAML but it is not easy. The value in the mapping for `three` has to be some instance of a class different from a normal string, otherwise the YAML dumper doesn't know that it has to do something special and that instance is dumped as string with quotes. On loading scalars with single quotes need to be created as instances of this class. And apart from that you probably don't want the keys of your `dict`/`mapping` scrambled as PyYAML does by default.

I do something similar to the above in my PyYAML derivative [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml/) for block style scalars:

```
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
one: valueOne
two: valueTwo
three: |-
  valueThree
"""

data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str)
assert ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data) == yaml_str
```

doesn't throw an assertion error.

---

To start with the dumper, you can "convert" the `valueThree` string:

```
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml.scalarstring import ScalarString

yaml_str = """\
one: valueOne
two: valueTwo
three: 'valueThree'
"""

class SingleQuotedScalarString(ScalarString):
    def __new__(cls, value):
        return ScalarString.__new__(cls, value)

data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str)
data['three'] = SingleQuotedScalarString(data['three'])
```

but this cannot be dumped, as the dumper doesn't know about the `SingleQuotedScalarString`. You can solve that in different ways, the following extends `ruamel.yaml`'s `RoundTripRepresenter` class:

```
from ruamel.yaml.representer import RoundTripRepresenter
import sys

def _represent_single_quoted_scalarstring(self, data):
    tag = None
    style = "'"
    if sys.version_info < (3,) and not isinstance(data, unicode):
        data = unicode(data, 'ascii')
    tag = u'tag:yaml.org,2002:str'
    return self.represent_scalar(tag, data, style=style)

RoundTripRepresenter.add_representer(
    SingleQuotedScalarString,
    _represent_single_quoted_scalarstring)

assert ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data) == yaml_str
```

Once again doesn't throw an error. The above can be done in PyYAML and the `safe_load`/`safe_dump` in principle, but you would need to write code to preserve the key ordering, as well as some of the base functionality. (Apart from that PyYAML only supports the older YAML 1.1 standard not the YAML 1.2 standard from 2009).

To get the loading to work without using the explicit `data['three'] = SingleQuotedScalarString(data['three'])` conversion, you can add the following before the call to `ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load()`:

```
from ruamel.yaml.constructor import RoundTripConstructor
from ruamel.yaml.nodes import ScalarNode
from ruamel.yaml.compat import text_type

def _construct_scalar(self, node):
    if not isinstance(node, ScalarNode):
        raise ConstructorError(
            None, None,
            "expected a scalar node, but found %s" % node.id,
            node.start_mark)

    if node.style == '|' and isinstance(node.value, text_type):
        return PreservedScalarString(node.value)
    elif node.style == "'" and isinstance(node.value, text_type):
        return SingleQuotedScalarString(node.value)
    return node.value

RoundTripConstructor.construct_scalar = _construct_scalar
```

There are different ways to do the above, including subclassing the `RoundTripConstructor` class, but the actual method to change is small and can easily be patched.

---

Combining all of the above and cleaning up a bit you get:

```
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml.scalarstring import ScalarString
from ruamel.yaml.representer import RoundTripRepresenter
from ruamel.yaml.constructor import RoundTripConstructor
from ruamel.yaml.nodes import ScalarNode
from ruamel.yaml.compat import text_type, PY2


class SingleQuotedScalarString(ScalarString):
    def __new__(cls, value):
        return ScalarString.__new__(cls, value)


def _construct_scalar(self, node):
    if not isinstance(node, ScalarNode):
        raise ConstructorError(
            None, None,
            "expected a scalar node, but found %s" % node.id,
            node.start_mark)

    if node.style == '|' and isinstance(node.value, text_type):
        return PreservedScalarString(node.value)
    elif node.style == "'" and isinstance(node.value, text_type):
        return SingleQuotedScalarString(node.value)
    return node.value

RoundTripConstructor.construct_scalar = _construct_scalar


def _represent_single_quoted_scalarstring(self, data):
    tag = None
    style = "'"
    if PY2 and not isinstance(data, unicode):
        data = unicode(data, 'ascii')
    tag = u'tag:yaml.org,2002:str'
    return self.represent_scalar(tag, data, style=style)

RoundTripRepresenter.add_representer(
    SingleQuotedScalarString,
    _represent_single_quoted_scalarstring)


yaml_str = """\
one: valueOne
two: valueTwo
three: 'valueThree'
"""

data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str)
assert ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data) == yaml_str
```

Which still runs without assertion error, i.e. with dump output equalling input. As indicated you can do this in PyYAML, but it requires considerably more coding.

---

With a more modern version (ruamel.yaml>0.14) you can do:

```
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True

data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

and preserve the single quotes.

Comment: Thank you for detailed walkthrough. I did not implement it yet, as I still hoped if there is any easier way (after all, I thought I just wanted to have single quotes in my string in yaml...) If I don't find easier solution, I will follow yours and come back with feedback.

Comment: Sometime since answering this question I implemented the option `preserve_quotes`, I updated the answer on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I am taking your `yaml` to have no quotes beforehand, the result will be same whether there were quotes before or not.

Here's how:

```
import yaml

myyaml = """
one: valueOne
two: valueTwo
three: valueThree
"""

# loading the yaml

yaml_dict = yaml.load(myyaml, yaml.FullLoader)
print(yaml_dict)

{'one': 'valueOne', 'two': 'valueTwo', 'three': 'valuethree'}

# Define the following class:

class SingleQuoted(str):
    pass

def single_quoted_presenter(dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_scalar('tag:yaml.org,2002:str', data, style="'")

yaml.add_representer(SingleQuoted, single_quoted_presenter)

yaml_dict.update(three = SingleQuoted('valuethree'))

# Now dump as yaml

yaml.dump(yaml_dict, sys.stdout, sort_keys=False, default_flow_style=False)

# save it in a file by using an open file instead of stdout
```

, which gives the required yaml as follows:

```
one: valueOne
two: valueTwo
three: 'valueThree'
```

Answer (score 0):

To sum up, according to **@Anthon**'s answer

After installation of lib (`pip install ruamel.yaml`)

Solution is like that:

```
import ruamel.yaml
import sys

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True

yaml_str = """\
one: valueOne
two: valueTwo
three: 'valueThree'
"""

data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)

with open('config.yml', 'a') as file:
    yaml.dump(data, file)
```